# Torsion-free Lie groups

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, lie-groups

Out of curiosity, I'm looking for some examples of Lie groups that are torsion-free.

For some reason (and perhaps there is a good reason), most torsion-free groups I've heard of are discrete. One Lie example that comes to mind is $\mathbb{R}^n$. Also, if $G$ is a Lie group and its torsion subgroup, call it $\Gamma$, is both normal and discrete, then $G/\Gamma$ provides another source of examples.

**Question 1:** What are some more examples of torsion-free Lie groups?

**Question 2:** Are there any examples that have non-trivial compact Lie subgroups?

Comment: The Heisenberg manifold is another example of torsion-free Lie group.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The group of real upper triangular matrices with $>0$ diagonal entries is a good example of a group without elemnt of finite order.

If a Lie group contains a compact group , this subgroup is a compact Lie group, as every closed subgroup of a Lie group is a Lie group (Chevalley). But a compact Lie group is either finite (hence torsion) or contains a maximal torus, hence $T^1$, the group of complex number of modulus 1, and therefore contains elemnets of order $n$ for every $n$.

Comment: A Lie group is torsion free if and only if its maximal compact subgroup is trivial (as Thomas said) which is true if and only if it is contractible if and only if it is simply connected and the Lie algebra contains no $ \mathfrak{so}_3(\mathbb{R}) $ subalgebras if and only if it is  some extension of copies of $ \tilde{SL_2}(\mathbb{R}) $ by a simply connected solvable Lie group. Luis said  $ \tilde{SL_2}(\mathbb{R}) $ and Thomas said upper triangular matrices and basically simply connected solvable = closed subgroup of upper triangular matrices so I'm just rephrasing what they said.

Answer (score 2):

A connected Lie group that is torsion-free and it is not isomorphic to a group of matrices is the universal cover of $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$. It is essentially the only semisimple (that is, with no infinite connected abelian subgroups) Lie group that is torsion-free. All the other torsion-free connected Lie groups are solvable and diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n$.

As well-explained above, if a Lie group is torsion-free then its maximal compact subgroup is trivial.